# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dependencies'

Tags: python, airflow, azure-data-factory

I have created a airflow pipeline(not an ADF pipeline) and i am trying it to run in managed airflow instance in ADF. but in airflow UI its showing "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dependencies".

Below is file structure in azure blob (i already linked the blob to airflow instance):

- airflow -
- ```
       dags - lottery_main.py (Dag file)
  ```
- ```
              dependencies - lottery_pb.py
  ```

Below is the code of my dag file,

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2LyV.png)

error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09Kd1.png)

One of more question, Can we run our custom tasks in managed airflow? or does it have to be only ADF pipeline in airflow DAG? (cause all resources on web just shows running ADF pipeline on managed airflow).

Answer (score 0):

In each subfolder which you want to use as a module, you must create a `__init__. py` file.

Therefore in the dependencies folder create the file.

Comment: thanks for the comment. still facing same error after adding the file.

Comment: Did you redeploy the container?